# Is there anyone tried Twitter OAuth on free hosting 0fees.net?

Tags: twitter

I am new to Twitter OAuth API.

I am trying to tune a piece of code like this, and I registered a free hosting on 0fees.net, and try to test some code and get familiar with OAuth.

But when I try to get the AuthencatieUrl I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'EpiOAuthException' in /home/vol3/0fees.net/fees0_6530770/htdocs/Twi/EpiOAuth.php:313 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol3/0fees.net/fees0_6530770/htdocs/Twi/EpiOAuth.php(290): EpiOAuthException::raise(NULL, NULL) #1 /home/vol3/0fees.net/fees0_6530770/htdocs/Twi/EpiOAuth.php(33): EpiOAuthResponse->__get('oauth_token') #2 /home/vol3/0fees.net/fees0_6530770/htdocs/Twi/sign-in.php(15): EpiOAuth->getAuthenticateUrl() #3 {main} thrown in /home/vol3/0fees.net/fees0_6530770/htdocs/Twi/EpiOAuth.php on line 313
```

I debugged a little bit, it seems that the token request is always null on the free hosting..

But the same code works on my localhost, the token is retrieved right and the AuthencationURL from Twitter is also OK.....but I could not give localhost URL as callback..

Have you guys know this problem?

Thanks & Regards.
Larry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem on my localhost.  Changing it to 127.0.0.1 on the URL fixed the problem for me.  However I know it doesn't quite answer your question, but anybody coming across this with a similar problem, knowing this tidbit may help.  Best